# Dynamically get the value and label attribute from <li> tag or its nested button in JS

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

- List item

am using an App Launcher Tile to display content in each list in a modal. This tile contains some text and a button. The li tag with tile is dynamically generated using a for loop. Now when the user clicks on the button I can get the respective button value and label in JS but when the user is clicking on any other area in the li tag then I am unable to get the button attributes value and label.

I tried to put the value and label with the click handler on the li tag. Still not working.

```
<template for:each={hList} for:item="aList">
    <li class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_1-of-3" key={aList.label} data-value={aList.value} onclick={handleClick} data-label={aList.label}>
        <div class="slds-app-launcher__tile slds-text-link_reset slds-is-draggable">
            <div class="slds-app-launcher__tile-figure">
                <span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar_large">
                    <abbr class="slds-avatar__initials slds-icon-custom-27" title={aList.label}>{aList.init}</abbr>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-app-launcher__tile-body">
                <lightning-button class="slds-button" style="font-size:larger!important; font-weight:500!important; text-align:left!important;" label={aList.label} variant="base"></lightning-button>
                <div class="slds-wrap">
                    {aList.description}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</template>
```

JS:

```
handleClick(event) {
    const value = event.currentTarget.dataset.value;
    const label = event.currentTarget.dataset.label;
    console.log('value:', value, 'label:', label);
}
```

I have updated my code here to reflect the latest changes as suggested but still the value is coming blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

1. Instead li need to put the onclick in the ul tag
2. Have data-label and data-value in every child tags
3. for the button have a simple value and label attribute
4. And in the JS handle both scenarios

HTML:

```
<ul class="slds-grid slds-grid_pull-padded slds-wrap slds-var-m-around_small" onclick={handleClick} >
    <template for:each={hList} for:item="aList">
        <li class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_1-of-3" key={aList.label} data-value={aList.value} data-label={aList.label}>
            <div class="slds-app-launcher__tile slds-text-link_reset slds-is-draggable" data-label={aList.label} data-value={aList.value}>
                <div class="slds-app-launcher__tile-figure" data-label={aList.label} data-value={aList.value}>
                    <span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar_large" data-label={aList.label} data-value={aList.value}>
                        <abbr class="slds-avatar__initials slds-icon-custom-27" title={aList.label} data-label={aList.label} data-value={aList.value}>{aList.init}</abbr>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-app-launcher__tile-body" data-label={aList.label} data-value={aList.value}>
                    <lightning-button class="slds-button" style="font-size:larger!important; font-weight:500!important; text-align:left!important;" value={aList.value} label={aList.label} variant="base"></lightning-button>
                    <div class="slds-wrap" data-label={aList.label} data-value={aList.value}>
                        {aList.description}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
handleClick(){
        if(event.target.dataset.label){
            payload = {
                label: event.target.dataset.label,
                value: event.target.dataset.value
            }
        }else{
            payload = {
                label: event.target.label,
                value: event.target.value
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) identifies the element on which the event occurred, therefore it may be a descendant of `li` element. It works with base components due to [event retargeting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/events-handling.html#event-retargeting) (emphasis mine):

> When an event bubbles up the DOM, if it crosses the shadow boundary, **the value of `Event.target` changes to match the scope of the listener**. This change is called “event retargeting.” The event is retargeted so the listener can’t see into the shadow DOM of the component that dispatched the event

You need [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget): it identifies the element to which the event handler has been attached, `li` or `lightning-button` in your case.

I would define custom [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) for both label and value on `li` element and remove the `preventDefault` from the handler and the `onclick` from the button, i.e.

```html
<li class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_1-of-3" key={ahList.label} data-value={aList.value} data-label={aList.label} onclick={handleClick}>
```

```html
<lightning-button class="slds-button" style="font-size:larger!important; font-weight:500!important; text-align:left!important;" label={aList.label} variant="base"></lightning-button>
```

```js
handleClick(event) {
    const value = event.currentTarget.dataset.value;
    const label = event.currentTarget.dataset.label;
    console.log('value:', value, 'label:', label);
    const payload = {
        label,
        value
    };
}
```

Clicking on the button the event will bubble up to the `li` element, since the latter is an ancestor, so it's enough handling it just on that element.

By the way, in the payload object you assigned the value to the label property and vice versa, I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the catch for the label and value assignment. But the solution you suggested didnt work for me. It showing blank in the console.log. I was also thinking using closest() but didn't work

Comment: @Akash I edited the answer, please try again

Comment: I tried again but still, the value and label is coming blank for me.

Comment: @Akash Did you update the li element? I added a `data-label` attribute there and removed the data-attributes from the button

Comment: See my updated code above as per your suggestions still it is coming blank.